# Python, Webkit: how to get the DOM after the page has loaded?

Tags: python, webkit, gtk, pygtk

In my code I've connected to the WebView's load-finished event. The particular callback function takes a webview object and frame object as arguments. Then I tried executing get_dom_document() on the frame & the webview objects respectively. It seems this method doesn't exist for those objects...

PS: i started with the tips i got here http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/

UPDATE (11-Sep-2010): I think the link I shared relates to a new & different project. Its not a solution per se. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

it's definitely there.

and you can't just "take the tips from http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/" you actually have to COMPILE THE CODE (reason: standard pywebkitgtk DOES NOT have W3C DOM accessor functions).

then take a look in pythonwebkit/pywebkitgtk/examples and run browser.py and you'll see what  to do.

l.

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to mention (and it wasn't on the documentation, which i've now updated): you specifically need to check out the "python_codegen" branch, otherwise you just end up with plain vanilla webkit.  which is of absolutely no use to you.